# how to make a validation field optional when edit in php codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a form to add and update. so, i want to show a field as optional like when i'm adding it has to show validation error and when editing the same field doesn't ask validation error. 
here is code

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Job Title', 'trim|required|min_length[5]');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('description', 'Job Description', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('qualification', 'Job Qualification', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('mskills', 'Job Mandatory Skills', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('askills', 'Job Advantage Skills', 'trim');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('minexp', 'Job Min Experience', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('maxexp', 'Job Max Experience', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('postedon', 'Job Posted On', 'trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('postedby', 'Job Posted By','trim|required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('salary', 'Job Salary', 'trim|required');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
            {
                echo json_encode(array('st'=>0, 'msg' => validation_errors()));
            }
```

here i want to show optional field as

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('askills', 'Job Advantage Skills', 'trim');
```

Comment: Optional based on what condition?

Comment: <td width="10" align="left"><span class="required">*</span>Job Advantage Skills</td>
      <td align="left"><input name="askills" type="text"id="askills"style="width:350px;"value="<?php echo $job_advantage_skills;?>"/></td>  here i'm getting data dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a check condition to edit or add trigger. Make a hidden field and check it's edit mode or add mode and pass value form hidden

```
<input type='hiddden' name='checkform' value='add/edit'> // value change on runtime
```

then check

```
if($this->input->post('checkform') == 'add')
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('askills', 'Job Advantage Skills', 'trim|required');
else 
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('askills', 'Job Advantage Skills', 'trim');
```